# jQuery excluding certain columns from selection

Tags: jquery

I have a table where each row is clickable. Some columns in this table have links in them. I'd like to exclude 'link' columns from jQuery selection.

My first column, and third column contains links, so I'm doing the following after iterating through each row in the table:

```
row.children('td:gt(2)') // for column 3+
row.children('td:lt(2)') // for columns 0 and 1
```

Is there any way to join these two lines?

Answer (score 1):

```
row.children('td:gt(2), td:lt(2)')
```

**edit**: ah, artlung beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
row.children('td:gt(2),td:lt(2)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `:not` with `:eq` [selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/eq#index)...

```
row.find('td:not(:eq(2))')
```

or `:not` with the `:nth-child` [selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/nthChild#index)

```
row.children('td:not(:nth-child(3))')
```

*NOTE: `:eq` index starts with zero while the `:nth-child` selector starts with one.

I was going to use `children` for the `:eq` selector example, but it only worked on the first row.